# Moto X(1G) not updating. Gives error during update

Tags: moto-x

My MotoX is not updating. It is giving error during installation and restart it. Even I uninstall SuperSU by unroot option. My mobile is rooted how can i do unroot it. Because some banking apps is not working due to root set

Answer (score 1):

You must have a completely stock, unmodified device to take an OTA... No root, no TWRP, to Xposed, nothing. You have changed the /system partition so you cannot take an OTA. You need to restore your device to pure stock condition by flashing a factory firmware image or restore your TWRP backup from before any modifications to the device.

Comment: Thanks @acejavelin for your help....can u provide some links from where i can easily get the original factory firmware image

Comment: https://forum.xda-developers.com/moto-x/general/moto-x-return-to-100-stock-using-one-t3552256